# SQL query to find records if and only if join table contains all of a list of values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables that are joined by an association table. The requirement is to find only records in price table that include all of the menu codes in a list and only those in the list. The data (simplified) looks like this

```
price Table
price_id | site
----------------
1001     | 150
1002     | 151
1003     | 152
1004     | 153
```

```
menu Table
menu_id  | code   
------------------
5001     | 10000
5002     | 10001
5003     | 10002
5004     | 10003
```

```
price_menu Table
price_id | menu_id
------------------
1001     | 5002
1002     | 5002
1002     | 5003
1003     | 5002
1003     | 5003
1003     | 5004
```

Joining price and menu through price_menu, you would get

```
price joined with price_menu joined with menu
price_id | site  |  menu_id  | code
------------------------------------
1001     | 150   |  5002     | 10001
1002     | 151   |  5002     | 10001
1002     | 151   |  5003     | 10002
1003     | 152   |  5002     | 10001
1003     | 153   |  5003     | 10002
1003     | 153   |  5004     | 10003
```

So, if I wanted to find prices that are associated with menu.code=10001 and menu.code=10002, and only those codes, I should get the record with price_id=1002 only. The record with price_id=1001 has only one of the two menu.codes and the record with price_id=1003 has and addition menu. Therefore, only record(s) for price_id=1002 should be returned.

I came up with this query. However, the problem is that there could be many menus associated with a price and it would get too large and probably slow as every menu you add to the query you need another subquery.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *,
  (SELECT code AS mycode FROM price AS pc1 
   INNER JOIN price_menu AS pm1 ON pc1.id=pm1.price_id 
   JOIN menu AS m1 ON pm1.menu_id=m1.id
   WHERE pc1.id=pc.id
   AND m1.code = '1571403743330'
) AS data1,
  (SELECT code AS mycode FROM price AS pc2 
   INNER JOIN price_menu AS pm2 ON pc.id=pm2.price_id 
   JOIN menu AS m2 ON pm2.menu_id=m2.id
   WHERE pc2.id=pc.id
   AND m2.code = '1571403754395'
) AS data2
FROM price AS pc ) AS outerquery
WHERE data1 = '1571403743330'
AND data2 = '1571403754395'
```

This will produce one row per price found. However, there is no requirement that it be a single row. Can anyone suggest an alternative that would not require an additional subquery per menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your simplified example, you could achieve what you want with this query, which checks that the number of menu codes for a price (`COUNT(m.code)`) is 2 and that they are `10001` and `10002`:

```
SELECT p.price_id, p.site
FROM price p
JOIN price_menu pm ON pm.price_id = p.price_id
JOIN menu m ON m.menu_id = pm.menu_id
GROUP BY p.price_id, p.site
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN m.code IN (10001, 10002) THEN 1 END) = COUNT(m.code) 
   AND COUNT(m.code) = 2
```

Output:

```
price_id    site
1002        151
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xyFEhNUVGax2ZXSk8ysTpV/0)

Comment: That seem to work. I tried this approach. However, I think I ran afoul because I was adding columns from the joined tables. If you add the column m.menu_id to the select columns and group by clause, it will not work. I guess I don't understand GROUP BY, but why would it no longer work?

Comment: @codering because there is a 1:1 relationship between m.menu_id and m.code, adding m.menu_id to the GROUP BY will mean that you can only have one value of m.code for each row, making all the COUNT values 1 (and so the `HAVING COUNT(m.code) = 2` condition will never be true. You can get an array of the m.menu_id values in the result by adding `ARRAY_AGG(m.menu_id) AS menu_ids` to the query e.g. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xyFEhNUVGax2ZXSk8ysTpV/1

Comment: I case someone want to see what @Nick is referring to without going to db-fiddle.com:


```SELECT p.price_id, p.site, ARRAY_AGG(m.menu_id) AS menu_ids
FROM price p
JOIN price_menu pm ON pm.price_id = p.price_id
JOIN menu m ON m.menu_id = pm.menu_id
GROUP BY p.price_id, p.site
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN m.code IN (10001, 10002) THEN 1 END) = COUNT(m.code) 
   AND COUNT(m.code) = 2```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this using aggregation and having:

```
select pm.price_id
from menu m join
     price_menu pm
     on m.menu_id = pm.menu_id
group by pm.price_id
having count(distinct pm.code) = 2 and
       count(distinct case when pm.code in (1001, 1002) then pm.code end)) = 2;  -- number of things you are looking for
```

Note:  If there are no duplicate codes for a given price id, then use `count()` rather than `count(distinct)`.

In Postgres, you can use arrays for this information:

```
select pm.price_id
from menu m join
     price_menu pm
     on m.menu_id = pm.menu_id
group by pm.price_id
having count(distinct pm.code) = array_length(array[1, 2]) and
       count(distinct case when pm.code = any(array[1, 2]) then pm.code end)) = array_length(array[1, 2]);
```

This makes it easier to pass the array in as a parameter.